# Delphi places .exe in unexpected folder

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

...at least to me it's the wrong folder. Instead of putting the .exe in

> d:\projectfolder

it puts it in

> d:\projectfolder\Win32\Debug

This is the first time this happens; previously it created the file in the project folder. I've looked in the project options, but I can't seem to find the .exe location there. How can I change this back?

*(I'm using XE3)*

Comment: `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)` is my default Output directory folder. This means that depending on platform, the exe is directed to the selected platform subdirectory and config specifies whether it is a release or debug subdirectory.

Comment: @LURD - Thanks for your reply. I now understand what Platform and Config stand for. What I wonder is how this value got changed.

Comment: It is the default setup. Note that there are specific settings for platform/debug/release targets.

Comment: *Delphi places .exe in wrong folder* no it doesnt

Comment: To make sure you don't get more down votes, I've changed the title of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Project** -> **Options** -> **Delphi compiler** -> **Output directory**. Thats the place where you change your setting.

Comment: Thanks. Seems I missed it because of its cryptic content: **.\$(Platform)\$(Config)** :-)

Comment: `$(Platform)` and `$(Config)` are placeholders that the compiler/linker fills in based on the active platform+configuration that the project is being built for.  In the Project Manager, you must have had the "Win32" platform and the "Debug" build configuration active. That is why the file was put in the "Win32\Debug" subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

You can always replace ".\$(Platform)\$(Config)" with ".\" and it will output the exe file to the folder where the source code is located.